# How can I update a .jpg on SharePoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, webrequest

I got an old script that updates a pictures once per day on our SharePoint.
What the script did before the upgrade to SharePoint 365, is to make a photo with a webcam, saves the photo locally and then it uploads the photo to a SharePoint. It works fine.

But since we upgrade to SharePoint 365, the last step doesn't work anymore.

That is the old code for uploading it to SharePoint.

```
# Upload to Sharepoint
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $SharepointCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($SharepointUser, ($SharepointPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) )  
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $SharepointUrl -Method Put -InFile "$Path\webcam.jpg" -ContentType 'image/jpg' -Credential $SharepointCredentials -UseBasicParsing | Out-Null
```

I think that the problem is on `Invoke-WebRequest` and that `Put` doens't work anymore. Do you know if there is a new method to change or update the file?

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to upload files to Office 365 SharePoint library using CSOM via powershell. Hopefully that will get you on the right track.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2014/02/19/office-365-powershell-script-to-upload-files-to-a-document-library-using-csom/

Comment: Tanks for the response.
Do you know, if the "Invoke-WebRequest" doesn't work with the "Put"?

Comment: The 'Invoke-RestMethod' with -InFile may do the trick. I am not sure about Put, would try using Post. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 0):

[`Credentials` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.utility.activities.invokewebrequest.credential(v=vs.85).aspx) in `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet does not support SharePoint Online *claims based authentication*, it supports only authentication schemes such as basic, digest, NTLM, and Kerberos authentication.

To perform *authenticated* request in SharePoint Online using user credentials  [`SharePointOnlineCredentials` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) could be utilized as demonstrated below:

```
function Connect-SPO ([string] $Username, [string]$Password, [string]$Url) {

    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force))
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    $AuthenticationCookie = $Context.Credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie($Url, $true)
    $WebSession = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
    $WebSession.Credentials = $Context.Credentials
    $WebSession.Cookies.SetCookies($Url, $AuthenticationCookie)

    $FormsDigest = $Context.GetFormDigestDirect()
    $WebSession.Headers['X-RequestDigest'] = $FormsDigest.DigestValue

    $Context.Dispose()
    return $WebSession
}
```

Then your script for uploading a file could be modified like this:

```
#Connect
$Session = Connect-SPO -Username $Username -Password $Password -Url $WebUrl
# Upload file
$targetFileUrl = "$WebUrl/documents/$($FileInfo.Name)"  #set target file url 
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $targetFileUrl -Method Put -WebSession $Session -InFile $filePath
```

[SPOUploadFile.ps1](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/9a25f1687428c16cad4f0de0dcc5c23b)